# flutter how to get my code working maybe with a listener or callback? (EDITED)

Tags: flutter, callback, listener, provider, rerender

What I want to achive is that I want my list of food objects to be rerendered in the FoodList class when I add a new food in the WelcomeScreen class. Below I have relevant code from the two classes. My problem seems to be that the FoodList class is not rendered when I add a new object!? I have tried to use a ChangeNotifierProvider to the FoodList and from the WelcomeScreen called a setFoodList method that calls a notifyListeners method but it doesnt seem to work.

The code logic should be that the app from beginning loads images that are in the app and then the user should be able to add images with imagepicker that also are being saved to the database.

Any Ideas are much appreciated!

My relevant code is.

**FoodList class:**

```
getChildrenOfFoodBrainList(List<Food> foodList) {
    //final foodList = Provider.of<FoodBrain>(context).getFoodList();
    return List.of(foodList.map((food) => ImageCircle(
          image: food.imageDb == null ? food.fileName! : food.imageDb!,
          displayName: food.displayName!,
          text: food.text,
        )));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => FoodBrain(),
      child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Consumer<FoodBrain>(builder: (context, foodBrain, _) {
              return Column(children: <Widget>[
                AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  actions: [
                    IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
                  ],
                ),
                   
                Expanded(
                  child: Center(
                    
                    child: GridView.count(
                      primary: false,
                      crossAxisCount: 4,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      
                      
                      children:
                          getChildrenOfFoodBrainList(foodBrain.getFoodList()),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

**WelcomeScreen class:**

```
Future<File?> saveImageToDatabase(_displayName, imageFile) async {
    final file = File(imageFile!.path);
    String imgString = Utility.base64String(file.readAsBytesSync());

//Create new food object
    setState(() {
      Food food = new Food(
          displayName: _displayName,
          fileName: null,
          imageDb: imgString,
          text: null);

      //Save food image to database
      dbHelper.save(food);

      //Add food to FoodList
      brain.addFoodToList(food);
      
      //call notifylistener from FoodBrain class
      brain.setFoodList(brain.getFoodList());
      

      print(brain.getDisplayName());
    });

    
  }
```

**This is code for running save image from the WelcomeScreen:**

```
//Value passed from userInput
  _imageFile = imageFile;
                                                  
   await saveImageToDatabase(
     _displayName, imageFile);
   Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

**FoodBrain class:**
Class that use notify listeners

```
 void setFoodList(List<Food> newList) {
    _foodList = newList;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

**DBHelper class:**
Class that initialize and uses various methods to db con.

```
class DBHelper {

  static Database? _db;
  static const String ID = 'id';
  //static const String Path = 'path';
  static const String Name = 'displayName';
  static const String TABLE = 'photosTable';
  static const String ImageDb = 'imageDb';
  static const String DB_NAME = 'photos.db';

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db!;
    }
    _db = await initDB();
    return _db!;
  }

  initDB() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, DB_NAME);
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return db;
  }

  _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE $TABLE ($ID INTEGER, $Name TEXT, $ImageDb TEXT)');
  }

  Future<Food> save(Food food) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    food.id = await dbClient.insert(TABLE, food.toMap());
    return food;
  }

  //Get all photos from db
  Future<List<Food>> getPhotos() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> maps = await dbClient.query(TABLE, columns: [ID, Name, ImageDb]);
    List<Food> photos = [];
    if (maps.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
        photos.add(Food.fromMap(maps[i]));
      }
    }
    return photos;
  }

  Future close() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    dbClient.close();
  }
}
```

**ImageCircle class:**
This class is displaying the image. Either from db or from local storage.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Material(
        elevation: 10.0,
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        color: Colors.transparent,
        //Here we check if its a String or database file image and convert to image
        child: Ink.image(
          image: widget.image is String
              ? Image.asset(widget.image).image
              : Utility.imageFromBase64String(widget.image).image,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          width: 90.0,
          height: 90.0,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                getImageToMapList(widget.image, widget.displayName);

                //Hide current snackbar on Click if exists. Maybe we need an if exists also?
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                getSnackBar();
              });
            },
            //check on lesson about value and how to use it (animations?)
            //Hmm hover does not exist on a phone? only when you have a mouse?
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**PS. I have now edited with some more classes.**

Answer (score 0):

normally it should work,
need to know what happen in this class

```
//Save food image to database
      dbHelper.save(food);

      //Add food to FoodList
      brain.addFoodToList(food);
      
      //call notifylistener from FoodBrain class
      brain.setFoodList(brain.getFoodList());
```

Comment: Hi, As you can see aboe it saves image to db and the second function adds a food object to foodlist. In the last function you call a function that nofityListeners().

Comment: did you check the food list after saving new food and apply notify listener that the new food is in the list, question did all food load and show in the welcome page?

Comment: The new food is inte list when I check from the welcomescreen class but not when I check from the foodlist class (I have to find a way to reload the foodbrain list from here?)